# Commiting changes to mirrored repository

Tags: git, nopcommerce

To begin working on new nopCommerce project I created a private git repository. I wanted to be able to pull the latest changes from the source so I duplicated the official nopCommerce repo (https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/). I want to commit a change to my private repository that adds custom theme to the project. Where should I commit the change to be able to easily pull and merge changes from the official repo later on? Also how being in the mirrored repository should affect my git workflow. On my recent projects I used the gitflow (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).

Answer (score 2):

If you have duplicated that original "upstream" repo into your own private Git repo, that means the local cloned copy you have on your workstation should now push to said private repo of yours.

That is because of the `git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored` command ([from the GitHub tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/)).
It allows you to pull from pull fro the original repo and push to your mirror.

However, if you intend to add your own commits, this private repo should be a fork, not a mirror.
That means:

- referencing the original repo as "`upstream`" (instead of the fetch url of the remote `origin`)

  ```
  git remote add upstream $(git remote get-url origin)
  ```
- setting both push and fetch url of origin to your private repo

  ```
  git remote set-url origin $(git remote get-url origin)
  ```

After that, you can apply to your private repo any workflow you want (like git-flow), while still being able to fetch from `upstream`, and merge (or rebase on top of) any new commits from the original repo now referenced as `upstream`)